# Run process in its own window

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I was playing around with Batch on my computer, and I wanted to run a process in its own window. I figured out how to get it to run in its own window, but I want the window to close when the process ends. How can I do this?

This code will run python 2's `python.exe` in its own window:

```
@echo off
start call "C:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe" %*
```

Is there a way I can assign the new window to some variable and check if it has finished running the process, then exit the new window?

Comment: Why do you use `start call "python"` and not `start "" "python"` ?

Comment: @Endoro Because I didn't know I could do the empty string. I knew that if I removed `call`, it didn't work properly

Comment: FYI - If the first argument to START is enclosed within quotes, then it is interpreted to be the title of the window. If your target program requires quotes because of spaces, as in your case, then you must provide a title. The empty quotes just provides an empty title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

START via CMD /C, and the window will close once the command ends.

Also, as Endoro said in his comment, you should not need CALL

```
@start cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe" %*
```